# What is affecta modifying in this sentence from Fabulae Faciles?

Tags: grammar-identification

In the following sentence from Fabulae Faciles, I cannot figure out what `affecta` is modifying:

> Vix vestem induerat Glauce, cum dolorem gravem per omnia membra sensit,
> et paulo post crudeli cruciatu affecta e vita excessit.

Affecta appears to be feminine. I would have expected it to be modifying him, Glaucus, so it should be affectus right, not affecta???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Glauce* is feminine (which you just now figured out). One way to tell in the future is that Greek names that end in -e are feminine - that 'e' is actually the Greek eta, and they're all feminine first declension. The masculine first declension names end in alpha sigma or eta sigma. So Glauce has to be a daughter.

Answer (score 0):

Ooop, never mind, Gauce is a female. My mistake. I was thinking she was a son, but she is the daughter of Creon.